Requests to Sharepoint API REST
I'm attempting to access a specific SharePoint site via the REST API. I'm aware that there are specific Office 365 libraries and the Graph API available for this purpose.
I've successfully obtained the access token, but when I try to use it to access the site, I encounter a 401 error with the following message:

401 error: {'error_description': "Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was thrown."}

I've ensured that my application has all the necessary permissions. We've tried granting permissions both from SharePoint to the API and via XML with the following configuration:
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
 
<AppPermissionRequest
 
Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection" 
     Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>

Below is the Python request code that's resulting in the 401 error:
grant_type = "client_credentials"

data = {
    'client_id': client_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
}

token_url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token" 

data.update({
    'grant_type': grant_type,
    'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
})

response = requests.post(token_url, data=data)
response_data = response.json()
access_token = response_data.get("access_token")

headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
          'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',

}


URL_SITE = 'https://capitalenergysau.sharepoint.com/sites/Data_Connections/_api/web'

session = requests.Session()

session.get(URL_SITE, headers = headers).json()

I have tried changing the URL_SITE, changing permissions over the app, etc
